# Python - é possível usar lambda em print com format (f ou .format)?

Tags: python, expressões-lambda

Pesquisei por **lambda** e `print` e não encontrei nada do que eu imaginei, ou seja, é possível fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
mil = num//1000
print(f'O número tem {mil} {lambda milhar if (mil == 1) else milhares}')
```

ou

```
print('O número tem {} {}'. format(mil, lambda milhar if (mil == 1) else milhares)
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já mencionado pelo Renan, o problema pode ser resolvido mais fácil através do uso do operador ternário, porém, é possível sim adicionar o `lambda` junto com o `print`.

```
num = 3000
mil = num//1000

# Utilizando lambda
print(f'O número tem {mil} {(lambda : "milhar" if mil == 1 else "milhares")()}')

# Utilizando apenas operador ternário
print(f'O número tem {mil} {"milhar" if mil == 1 else "milhares"}')
```

O `lambda` no fim das contas retorna uma expressão, então precisa ser chamada (call) para retornar o valor.

Comment: Camilo, muito obrigado. Acredite, eu havia montado esse lambda que vc criou, mas sem os dois () ao final, pois não os havia visto nos exemplos de lambda que encontrei por ai.  Agora ficou claro o caráter do lambda 'uma expressão', deve ser chamada. Funcionou perfeito, como vc já sabia. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa neste caso não é lambda, mas utilizar operador ternário.
Segue um exemplo:

```
num = 1200
mil = int(num/1000)
print("o numero tem {} {}".format(mil, "milhar" if mil == 1 else "milhares"))
```

Comment: Renan, perfeito resolveu o problema do meu código, de fato esqueci completamente do ternário. Porém, fica a questão, print format e lambda trabalham em conjunto? Não achei exemplo ainda, talvez não possa. Muito obrigado.